# How to get the number of downloads of my own app on google play through api

Tags: api, google-play-console

I already got the service account with the private key; how can I use this info to fetch the number of daily downloads of my app on google play? I didn't find any API to call.
I want to write a python script to fetch these data daily.
Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: I am here looking for solution to this same problem. I don't think google has an API for this yet. Did you find an alternative?